# MPIO and ESXi 7.0 standalone

Tags: ipv6, esxi, iscsi, multipath

I'm trying to setup MPIO between ESXi 7.0 standalone (free license) and a SCST server.

I created 4 vmknics (vmk1,vmk2,vmk3,vmk4) with IPv6 addresses

(2001::1/64,2002::1/64,2003::1/64,2004::1/64)

and I assigned

(2001::2/64,2002::2/64,2003::2/64,2004::2/64)

to 4 different nics on the Linux box.

Each L3 segment resides on a different VLAN.

I do have also a vmk0 configured with IPv4 IP address.

When I do netstat on the SCST server I see it listens on 0.0.0.0:3260 and :::3260

I found this wonderful article but the commands on the ESXi hosts refer to the 4.0 version and on the ESXi 7.0 I do **NOT** have **esxcli swiscsi**

https://virtualgeek.typepad.com/virtual_geek/2009/01/a-multivendor-post-to-help-our-mutual-iscsi-customers-using-vmware.html

My understanding is that I have to bind the vmknic to the vmnic but I could not find any related documentation for CLI/ESXCLI on 7.0.

I still see one path instead of more than one for each of my devices:

```
[root@ESXi:~] esxcfg-mpath -b |grep -B1 "Adapter"| grep -v -e "--" |sed 's/Adapter.*//'
eui.3163656561363833 : SCST_FIO iSCSI Disk (eui.3163656561363833)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L2 LUN:2 state:active iscsi
eui.3363613336363835 : SCST_BIO iSCSI Disk (eui.3363613336363835)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L8 LUN:8 state:active iscsi
eui.3761663561303238 : SCST_FIO iSCSI CD-ROM (eui.3761663561303238)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L1 LUN:1 state:active iscsi
eui.3562393762313730 : SCST_BIO iSCSI Disk (eui.3562393762313730)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L5 LUN:5 state:active iscsi
eui.6631393662333130 : SCST_BIO iSCSI Disk (eui.6631393662333130)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L0 LUN:0 state:active iscsi
eui.6164373835346366 : SCST_FIO iSCSI CD-ROM (eui.6164373835346366)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L4 LUN:4 state:active iscsi
eui.3639313435343362 : SCST_FIO iSCSI CD-ROM (eui.3639313435343362)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L3 LUN:3 state:active iscsi
eui.3332653439383239 : SCST_BIO iSCSI Disk (eui.3332653439383239)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L6 LUN:6 state:active iscsi
eui.3762393937356132 : SCST_BIO iSCSI Disk (eui.3762393937356132)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L9 LUN:9 state:active iscsi
eui.3466376564643362 : SCST_BIO iSCSI Disk (eui.3466376564643362)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L10 LUN:10 state:active iscsi
eui.6233633835373866 : SCST_BIO iSCSI Disk (eui.6233633835373866)
   vmhba64:C0:T0:L7 LUN:7 state:active iscsi
```

The iSCSI software adapter seems to be linked to all the VMK nics

```
[root@ESXi:~] esxcli iscsi logicalnetworkportal list -A vmhba64
Adapter  Vmknic  MAC Address        MAC Address Valid  Compliant
-------  ------  -----------------  -----------------  ---------
vmhba64  vmk0    ac:1f:6b:98:19:a4               true      false
vmhba64  vmk1    00:50:56:66:f3:a2               true      false
vmhba64  vmk2    00:50:56:66:9b:7e               true      false
vmhba64  vmk3    00:50:56:68:b5:38               true      false
vmhba64  vmk4    00:50:56:61:ee:67               true      false
```

What am I'm missing?

Comment: Have you configured port binding on the iSCSI Software Adapter? I've had an issues, when binding didn't allow to have all paths available connected.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I realized what "binding a physical nic" to a VMK nic meant, i.e.

```
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set -a vmnic4 -p PG-iSCSI_01
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set -a vmnic5 -p PG-iSCSI_02
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set -a vmnic6 -p PG-iSCSI_03
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set -a vmnic7 -p PG-iSCSI_04
```

The requirements for the statements above are that for each portgroup only one active vmnic is active whilst the others are unused, i.e.

```
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set --active-uplinks=vmnic4 --portgroup-name=PG-iSCSI_01
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set --active-uplinks=vmnic5 --portgroup-name=PG-iSCSI_02
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set --active-uplinks=vmnic6 --portgroup-name=PG-iSCSI_03
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set --active-uplinks=vmnic7 --portgroup-name=PG-iSCSI_04
```

and of course after having created the portgroups

```
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup add --portgroup-name=PG-SCSI_01 -vswitch vSwitch1
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup add --portgroup-name=PG-SCSI_02 -vswitch vSwitch1
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup add --portgroup-name=PG-SCSI_03 -vswitch vSwitch1
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup add --portgroup-name=PG-SCSI_04 -vswitch vSwitch1
```

and after having added a vmknic to each portgroup

```
esxcli network ip interface add --interface-name=vmk1 --portgroup-name=PG-iSCSI_01
esxcli network ip interface add --interface-name=vmk2 --portgroup-name=PG-iSCSI_02
esxcli network ip interface add --interface-name=vmk3 --portgroup-name=PG-iSCSI_03
esxcli network ip interface add --interface-name=vmk4 --portgroup-name=PG-iSCSI_04
```

Let's rescan the iSCSI adapter (all if it is not a problem)

```
esxcli storage core adapter rescan -a
```

We can quickly check that all the paths are used for each device

```
for dev in $(esxcli storage core device list | grep -e '^[^\ ]' | xargs);do echo -n "Device: $dev Paths:"; path=$(esxcli storage core path list -d $dev | grep -e '^iqn'| wc -l); echo $path;done
Device: eui.3163656561363833 Paths:5
Device: eui.3363613336363835 Paths:5
Device: eui.3761663561303238 Paths:5
Device: eui.3562393762313730 Paths:5
Device: eui.6631393662333130 Paths:5
Device: eui.6164373835346366 Paths:5
Device: eui.3639313435343362 Paths:5
Device: eui.3332653439383239 Paths:5
Device: eui.6332303139666464 Paths:5
Device: eui.6233633835373866 Paths:5
```

Of course all the paths **must be** in **Active state**

```
esxcli storage core path list -d eui.3163656561363833 | awk '/^i/{dev=$0}/Runtime/{rn=$3}/State/{printf "%20s %7s %s\n",rn,$2,dev}'
    vmhba64:C0:T0:L7  active iqn.2019-05.com....-00023d000002,iqn.2020-02.l...l:bm01-1234abcd,t,1-eui.6233633835373866
    vmhba64:C5:T0:L7  active iqn.2019-05.com....-00023d000017,iqn.2020-02.l...l:bm01-1234abcd,t,1-eui.6233633835373866
    vmhba64:C4:T0:L7  active iqn.2019-05.com....-00023d000012,iqn.2020-02.l...l:bm01-1234abcd,t,1-eui.6233633835373866
    vmhba64:C3:T0:L7  active iqn.2019-05.com....-00023d00000d,iqn.2020-02.l...l:bm01-1234abcd,t,1-eui.6233633835373866
    vmhba64:C2:T0:L7  active iqn.2019-05.com....-00023d000008,iqn.2020-02.l...l:bm01-1234abcd,t,1-eui.6233633835373866
```